# Inheriting ArrayList property from superclass but assigning different types to it in child classes

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a superclass A that has a protected `ArrayList<Object> contentList`. And I have classes B and C that inherit from A.

Each of B and C initialise contentList in their constructor with ArrayList of different types

```
class B extends A
{
    public B (ArrayList<BContent> content)
    {
        contentList = content;
    }
...
}


class C extends A
{
    public C (ArrayList<CContent> content)
    {
        contentList = content;
    }
...
}
```

Both `BCOntent` and `CContent` and data structure subclasses from Object.

The compiler is complaining that this is not accepted and that I have to change the declaration type of `contentList`from `ArrayList<Object>` to `ArrayList<BCOntent>` or `ArrayList<CCOntent>`

I come from Objective-C background and this is possible due to dynamic type resolution. How can I achieve this in Java?

Cheers
AF

Comment: The compiler prevents such assignment because it isn't type safe. If compiler let assignments like `List<Object> contentList = new ArrayList<CContent>()` to pass it would lead to situation where any Object could be added to a contentList which is actually a CContent collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use generics.

```
class A<T> {
    protected List<T> content;
}

class B extends A<BContent> {
    ...
}
```

This means that `A` can be used with different possible types (`T`) as its content. `A<BContent>` holds `BContent`, and `A<CContent>` holds `CContent`.

Comment: Thanks a lot this has indeed solved my issue. Finally i understand what generics are all about :)

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayList<BContent>` is not `ArrayList<Object>` even if `BContent` is an `Object`.

But what you can do is,

```
public B (ArrayList<BContent> content)
{
    contentList = new ArrayList<>(content);
}
```

This way you are creating a new `ArrayList<Object>` with all the elements of `content`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a type bound in the member declaration :

```
protected ArrayList<? extends Object> contentList;
```

You don't have to change your constructors.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a generic type in the superclass

```
public class A<T> {
    protected List<T> contentList;
}
```

Then you can extend it with a concrete type

```
public class B extends A<BContent> {
    public B (List<BContent> content) {
        contentList = content;
    }
    ...
```

BTW, passing around `ArrayList` is usually a bad idea... use the more general `List` instead.