# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,List<Animal>> to Map<String,List<Dog>>

Tags: java, generics, casting, polymorphism, maps

I am having some trouble solving a problem with generics.  I have a list of "Cat" objects and a list of "Dog" objects that I need to pass into the same method.  The return type for that method is a Map of "String" and a "List of Animals"  I am trying to figure out a way to convert the Maps with the list of animals into a Map with a list of Cats or Dogs.

This works fine if I have a separate method for Cats and Dogs but I'm looking for a more flexible solution.

Lines getting the error in title:

```
catMap = PetStore.groupAnimalsByOwner(cats); 
dogMap = PetStore.groupAnimalsByOwner(dogs);
```

Note: this is a simplified example, I have to be able to use the Lists in the Maps as "Cat" or "Dog" objects.

```
    public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cat cat1 = new Cat("Jerry", "cat1");
        Cat cat2 = new Cat("Jerry", "cat2");
        Cat cat3 = new Cat("Fred", "cat3");

        List<Cat> cats = new LinkedList<Cat>();
        cats.add(cat1);
        cats.add(cat2);
        cats.add(cat3);

        Dog dog1 = new Dog("Frank", "dog1");
        Dog dog2 = new Dog("Jerry", "dog2");
        Dog dog3 = new Dog("Bob", "dog3");

        List<Dog> dogs = new LinkedList<Dog>();
        dogs.add(dog1);
        dogs.add(dog2);
        dogs.add(dog3);

        Map<String, List<Dog>> dogMap = new HashMap<String, List<Dog>>();
        Map<String, List<Cat>> catMap = new HashMap<String, List<Cat>>();

        // catMap should have 2 key/value pairs - key "Jerry" with a list containing cat1 and cat2
        // and a pair - key "Fred" with a list containing only cat3
        catMap = PetStore.groupAnimalsByOwner(cats); 

        // dogMap should have 3 key/value pairs - key "Frank" with a list containing dog1
        // key "Jerry" with a list containing dog2
        // Key "Bob" with a list containing dog3
        dogMap = PetStore.groupAnimalsByOwner(dogs);

    }

}
```

```
public class PetStore {

    //Grouping by owner
    public static Map<String, List<Animal>> groupAnimalsByOwner(List<? extends Animal> animals) {
        Map<String, List<Animal>> groupedMap = new HashMap<String, List<Animal>>();
        List<Animal> tempList = null;

        for (Animal summary : animals) {
            String consolidatedInvoiceId = summary.getOwner();
            tempList = groupedMap.get(consolidatedInvoiceId);
            if (tempList == null) {
                tempList = new LinkedList<Animal>();
            }
            tempList.add(summary);
            groupedMap.put(consolidatedInvoiceId, tempList);
        }

        return groupedMap;
    }
}
```

```
public interface Animal {

    public String getOwner();
}
```

```
  public class Cat implements Animal {

    private String owner;
    private String name;

    public Cat(String owner, String name) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void doCatStuff() {
        System.out.println("Do cat stuff");
    }

}
```

The Dog class is the same as Cat but with a doCatStuff method.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604266/inheriting-arraylist-property-from-superclass-but-assigning-different-types-to-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a [`List<Dog>` isn't a `List<Animal>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p), a `Map<String, List<Cat>>` is not a `Map<String, List<Animal>>`.

Make your `groupAnimalsByOwner` method generic, with `Animal` as an upper bound, so that `T` is inferred to be `Cat` (or `Dog`).  You'll need to replace `Animal` with `T` in the body of the method.

```
public static <T extends Animal> Map<String, List<T>> 
         groupAnimalsByOwner(List<? extends T> animals)
{
    Map<String, List<T>> groupedMap = new HashMap<String, List<T>>();
    List<T> tempList = null;

    for (T summary : animals) {
        String consolidatedInvoiceId = summary.getOwner();
        tempList = groupedMap.get(consolidatedInvoiceId);
        if (tempList == null) {
            tempList = new LinkedList<T>();
        }
        tempList.add(summary);
        groupedMap.put(consolidatedInvoiceId, tempList);
    }

    return groupedMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `List<Cat>` and `List<Dog>` to `List<Animal>`

maybe this will help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

You declared the method as returning `Map<String, List<Animal>>`.  This type is not compatible with `Map<String, List<Dog>>` because a `List<Animal>` is not compatible with `List<Dog>`.  Those are not compatible because the first declaration, `List<Animal>`, does not allow any subtypes of `Animal`.  Secondly, while all `Dog`s are `Animal`s, not all `Animal`s are `Dog`s.

For this scenario, what you need is a placeholder.

```
public static <T extends Animal> Map<String, List<T>>  groupAnimalsByOwner(List<T> animals) {
```